# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xpath/compiler/FuncLoader

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror

I am using Eclipse with Java 1.6 and have included following jar files in the build path
xalan-2.7.1.jar, xmlsec-1.1.jar, xmlsec-2.0.jar but I still get following error message when I compile the code:

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xpath/compiler/FuncLoader`

The code where its erroring out is:

`static { org.apache.xml.security.Init.init();  }`

Comment: You really should only include one of the xmlsec-x.x JARs in your classpath.

Comment: Is xlan jar is in your classpath ?

Comment: i suppose xlan-2.7.1.jar is xalan-2.7.1.jar, cause that class that cannot be found is from that library

Answer (score 7):

According to [this bug report](https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/EBR-738), Xalan 2.7.x does not have the `FuncLoader` class included. Try downgrading to Xalan 2.6.x.

Answer (score 1):

When not sure why a `NoClassDeFoundError` occurs, I find it useful to consult [findjar.com](http://www.findjar.com).

I find it interesting that, [for your specific case](http://www.findjar.com/class/org/apache/xpath/compiler/FuncLoader.html), various versions of xalan are listed but not the one you have in your classpath. Maybe there's something there?

Comment: Good tip, but got the jar detected

Answer (score 1):

Try with xmlsec-1.3.0.jar which is compatible with wss4j-1.6.16.jar